# "In tempo" versus "a tempo"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, prepositions

Ho visto queste due espressioni, "in tempo" e "a tempo", nei testi che ho letto. Per esempio, questa frase appartiene al racconto *La radura* di Marisa Madieri:

> «Se non la smette *in tempo*, finirà col coprirsi di ridicolo.»

Quest'altra frase invece è tratta da un [articolo del giornale La Repubblica](http://bari.repubblica.it/cronaca/2014/12/23/news/ilva-103624719/):

> «Un commissariamento che avrà una durata *a tempo*, di massimo 36 mesi, perché poi l'azienda dovrà essere venduta al miglior offerente che dovrà garantire produzione e ambiente ma non necessariamente i numeri dell'attuale forza lavoro.»

Non so quando devo usare "in tempo" e quando invece "a tempo". Potreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**In tempo**:
non in ritardo. Supponiamo che devi fare una cosa entro un certo termine, se la fai prima, allora l'avrai fatta *in tempo*. 
Es. "sono arrivato in tempo."

Si usa anche in espressioni del tipo "non ho fatto in tempo a mangiare prima di prendere il treno". È un po' diverso perché non è che puoi mangiare in ritardo, semplicemente non hai fatto in tempo a farlo prima.

**A tempo**: ci sono 2 modi di usarlo.

1. Per indicare che una cosa è a termine. Ad es. un contratto *a tempo determinato* vuol dire che dopo tot tempo finisce. Prima o poi finisce. Il commissariamento è *a tempo* nel senso che non può andare avanti per una durata indeterminata.
2. Si usa anche con lo stesso significato di *in tempo*, es. "non ho neanche fatto a tempo a bere il caffé prima di dover andare".

Ne aggiungo uno per completezza:

**Per tempo**: il dizionario lo dà come sinonimo di "di buon'ora", ma per me significa semplicemente che devi fare una cosa con un certo anticipo rispetto al termine così che non la fai in ritardo.

Ad es. se devi prendere un aereo, allora devi partire *per tempo*. Vuol dire che parti abbastanza prima così da non arrivare in ritardo.

Comment: Pignoleria: ci sarebbe anche l'espressione fissa "andare a tempo", anche se si applica solo alla musica (o metaforicamente per estensione).